# Is purchasing of points from webview is ok for Google Play Policy?

Tags: android

We are developing a quiz game which offers purchasing of points, which get deducted accordingly from the application.We are going to use third party to achieve this.Can we use webview for payment or is there any problem with Google Play Policy??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms and conditions of an app distribution channel, not programming. Please see [this Meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic) for a description of what is on-topic and off-topic for Stack Overflow regarding the Play Store and other distribution channels.

Answer (score 0):

No,
[Google policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html) does not allow to process payments of digital goods without going through Google Play In-App Billing. Check this to confirm [Google Play Developer Programme Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html).
Hope that helps.